# is there a way to detect if the disk tray is open in C#?

Tags: c#

I want to open a program when the user closes the disk tray empty.
I tried using `DriveInfo.IsReady` but it is set to `true` only if the tray is closed and media is inserted.

If the tray is closed and there is no media **or** if the tray is opened, `DriveInfo.IsReady` is set to `false`.

`Win32_LogicalDisk` also doesn't have anything helpful

Comment: You'll want `Win32_CDROMDrive` instead of `Win32_LogicalDisk`.

Comment: Hmm, apparent reliably getting the CD drive tray status is non-trivial on Windows - and may as well be impossible (because the CD drive hardware isn't obligated to accurately report its status to Windows, also remember that not all CD drives even have trays (such as slot-loaders and ye olde school caddy-loaded disc drives).

Comment: @Dai to be fair, talking about caddy-loaders as "olde school" may be burying the lede, since having optical drives at all is a rarity now